# How can I get a modified version of the current branch name as my commit message in .bashrc?

Tags: bash, git

Say I have my current branch as `STACK-123/this-is-my-branch`. In my .bashrc file, how can I run a function such that the commit message becomes a modified version of the branch name. Say I have the alias as `branch-to-commit-alias`:

```
$: branch-to-commit-alias
$: git log
Author: me
Date: <todays date>

   STACK-123: This is my branch
```

Comment: Are you asking how to change the way an existing commit message displays, or how to set a commit message for a new commit?

Comment: @chepner Creating a new commit with that message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shell function gives you the commit message `STACK 123: this is my branch` based **only** on the branch name.

```
branch-to-commit-alias () {
    local msg=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | sed 's|/|: |; s|-| |g')
    git commit -m "$msg"
}
```

However: Hiding `git commit` in such a function also hides any options you might want to add to `git commit`.

A more flexible way are git-hooks (see `git help hooks`): You can move the logic into the `prepare-commit-msg`. This hook will prepare the message you see in the editor. You can edit that message wit more info or just quit the editor and be done.

To do so write this script to `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg`:

```
#!/bin/sh

mv "$1" "$1.bak"
(
    git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | sed 's|/|: |; s|-| |g'
    cat "$1.bak"
) > "$1"
```

and make it executable:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is for *new* commit messages right?

Comment: Whatever arguments you pass to `branch-to-commit-alias` can be passed on: `git commit -m "$msg" "$@"`.

Comment: @A.H. This removes the first dash between `STACK-123`. How do I only remove the ones after the colon?

Comment: @AlanH: You can use `sed 'h; s|/.*||; x; s|^.*/| |; y/-/ /; x; G; y/\n/:/'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$: xmp() { git commit -m "$(git branch | sed -n '/^[*] / { s/^[*] \(.*\)/\1/; s,/,:,; s/-/ /g; p; }') $@"; }
```

then you can use it like a commit.

```
$: xmp
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

$: touch foo
$: git add foo
$: xmp
[master ac63834] master -
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo
$: git rm foo
rm 'foo'
$: xmp testing
[master ade608b] master - testing
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 foo
$: git log
commit ade608b32e45d586e6a72275939df12f4f50ee11 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Paul Hodges <Paul.Hodges@charter.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 24 16:29:56 2019 -0500

    master - testing

commit ac638346981b3104cb5185d5240fe218e827504a
Author: Paul Hodges <Paul.Hodges@charter.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 24 16:29:33 2019 -0500

    master -
```

I'd pick a better name, though. ;)

Comment: The string manipulation part doesn't work correctly. The `/` doesn't become `:`, and the dashes after the `/` don't become spaces. I also get a mysterious `-` at the very end of my commit message

Comment: The dash is in the function to separate branch stuff from anything you might want to manually add. Edit as you like. The conversions weren't included in the code, but are easy to add. Editing.